# Responsive design: How can I hide icon labels for small viewports using only CSS?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm working on a responsive layout using the [ZURB Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) framework.

I've added some icons (icon font spans) next to the text on a navigation bar, and here's what I would like to happen:

When the viewport is not wide enough to display all the navigation items on one line, the text labels for *only the items that would cascade to the next line* should be hidden and the font-size (icon size) for that item should be increased to a new fixed value.

I'm attaching 3 images (I just cheated with chrome inspector) to demonstrate what I'm looking for.

Is this possible without JavaScript? If so, how?

[image: Fullscreen]

[image: Windowed]

[image: Mobile]

Comment: Can you change the HTML code? Or do you need to follow one?

Comment: Sure, I can change anything.

Comment: "only the items that would cascade to the next line" - my gut tells me it's not really possible to express this constraint in CSS. You'd have to query on an item's x-position in the regular flow, and I've no idea whether that's even possible with scripting, much less in CSS. (Which traditionally doesn't let inspect the *result* of the layout step much.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution by iterating on the answer by [Charles-Edouard Coste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1844857/charles-edouard-coste). I am using [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) but I will first show its CSS output:

```
nav .nav-bar .icon {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  nav .nav-bar li:nth-child(1) .icon-label {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav .nav-bar li:nth-child(2) .icon-label {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  nav .nav-bar li:nth-child(3) .icon-label {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  nav .nav-bar li:nth-child(4) .icon-label {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  nav .nav-bar li:nth-child(5) .icon-label {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

This solution works hiding one label at each hundred pixel decrement. Unfortunately, it requires a new rule for each element in the list, and therefore it requires that the stylesheet either

1. have exact knowledge of the list length, or
2. include potentially unused directives up to a reasonable maximum length.

I have opted to create a [Sass mixin](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins) for reuse and to make the source less verbose.

```
@mixin iconlist( $min-width, $label-selector, $step: 100px, $count: 5 )
  //
   The iconlist() mixin will responsively hide labels, 
   starting from the last, as the viewport width is decreased.

   This can be included in a horizontal list to show only icons
   on small screens, while still displaying as many labels as
   possible, assuming items are prioritized from most important
   to least.

  @for $i from 1 through $count
    $max-width: $min-width + ( $step * $i )
    @media only screen and (max-width: #{$max-width})
      li:nth-child(#{$i})
        #{$label-selector}
          display: none
```

**Usage**

```
.nav-bar
  // Responsively hide 0-3 labels from the end of the list.
  @include iconlist(600px, '.icon-label', 100px, 3)
```

If anyone cares to suggest a refactor that results in smaller or better-decoupled CSS, that would be awesome! But I'm not sure how it would be done.

Answer (score 3):

So...

Here is the solution suggested by W3C [to hide a portion of the link text](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C7):

```
height: 1px;
width: 1px;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
top: -10px;
```

Let's say that you want to use this HTML code:

```
<li><a href="#">Documentation</a></li>
```

Here is a solution if you want (for instance) a 30px => 50px transformation:

```
li {
  padding-left : 30px;
  line-height  : 30px; /* vertical align */
  background   : transparent url(http://placehold.it/30) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
}

/* Put whatever you want as a size here */
@media (max-width: 600px) { 
  li {

    background : transparent url(http://placehold.it/50) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    width      : 50px;
    height     : 50px;
  }
  a {
    height   : 1px;
    width    : 1px;
    position : absolute;
    overflow : hidden;
    top      : -1000px; 
  }
}
```

This solution force you to create 2 versions for your image. But actually resizing images is not recommended, so dealing with 2 versions of one image is not really a bad idea.

In your particular case, if you are using font icons, you may probably use this kind of HTML code:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="icon">X</span>
    <span class="text">Documentation</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

So you can just adapt CSS code this way:

```
span {
  font-size : medium;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) { 
  span.icon {
    font-size : x-large;
  }
  span.text {
    height   : 1px;
    width    : 1px;
    position : absolute;
    overflow : hidden;
    top      : -1000px; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but note that I am using a vector-based icon font, not a background image.

Comment: Thanks, giving that a try.

Comment: I came up with a solution based on yours that works quite nicely, though for long lists it can be a bit verbose.

Comment: Your solution correctly hides the label text when a minimum width is reached, but it does so for all labels in the list.

I was looking for a solution which hides only the labels necessary to render the list on one line, starting from the last list item.

I will post my solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this?

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) 
.noshow {
display: none;
}
```

And in your HTML markup, apply the "noshow" class to the text you want to hide.

Comment: Haha, got voted-down? We are all saying the same thing, just with more/less detail.

Comment: Sorry, your answer was not incorrect exactly, but it did not satisfy the requirements posed by the question. Thank you for your help, regardless!

Answer (score -1):

Edit to your liking and needs.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 

  html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  }

  .tooBig {
    display: none;
  }

}
```